# Basic authentication with Apache

Tags: php, api, authentication

I have basic authentication enabled on an Apache server. The server is hosting an API that I implemented and I want to do is call this API from my PHP script. I got as far as figuring out how to create a header:

```
$user = 'my_name_api';
$pwd = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$auth_string = $user . ':' . $pwd;
$auth_b64 = base64_encode($auth_string);
$header   = 'Authorization: Basic ' . $auth_b64;
```

How do I include the $header in my API calls? I am looking for something other than cURL, and I am NOT using any environments like zend, etc. (saw some example for Zend, etc., but I am not using any of those).

Comment: Are you running this PHP code on the same server as the API? You'd be better off invoking the php code directly, rather than doing full-blown local http call.

Comment: cURL is not available on all PHP installations.

Comment: cUrl is not an option for my server

Comment: I am running this on the same server as the API. I am not sure what you mean by invoking the code directly.

Comment: @user1765002: instead of doing an http request to the same server, which is highly inefficient, simply load up the api code directly with `include()` or whatever, and call whatever functions you need directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried fopen / file_get_contents?

Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

or here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

and let me know how it goes...

airyt

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need SSL or proxy support, you can use `file_get_contents()` with a stream context. The stream context can contain HTTP headers:

```
$opts = array
(
  'http'=>array
  (
    'method' => "GET",
    'header' => "Authorization: ..."
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com', false, $context);
```

More on this [here](http://php.net/stream-context-create).

Comment: I don't have a proxy issue, but the server requires SSL. Can't I replace http://www.example.com with https://www.example.com?

Comment: Only if you have the openssl lib installed with PHP.

Comment: I checked with the server admin, and he said that openssl is built into the standard apache release, however I believe that http is still available